# Doppler effect differs when the entity moving is different

Tags: homework-and-exercises, reference-frames, observers, doppler-effect

[image: calculated results for different cases]

Why is the doppler shift different when whether the source is moving or the observer? Although they are traveling at the same speed. Noticing that the difference can't be neglected when the speed is a big fraction of the speed of sound.

Answer (score 1):

You would think that it wouldn't matter whether it's the source or the observer that's moving in the doppler effect. An argument might be that when the observer is moving, you can just choose a difference reference frame in which the observer is instead stationary and the source is moving, or vice versa.

The problem with this argument is that the medium, air, can also be travelling. In shifting reference frames, the velocity of the medium is also changing, so we can't change reference frames without also altering the physics of the problem. There's actually a version of the formula that takes the velocity of the medium into account, that resolves this apparent paradox.

The result is that the source and observer velocities aren't interchangeable.

Comment: @BobBee : I do not understand your comment. Are you using colloquialisms? Please could you translate it into Plain English?

Comment: It seems clear from the numbers used in the OP's example that the problem involves audible sound waves in air...

Comment: Arthur = ether?

no Red = No need?

Damned speech -to-text..

Comment: No speech to text. Automatic spell and grammar or something checking on iPad. I didn't notice it was sound, so I will delete it.